# Ignition Gazebo Running Problem

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have installed ignition gazebo from https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/src/default/
I installed the ign-gazebo3 version
it builds successfully but when i run it via "ign gazebo" i get that error

......................................................................................................................................................

[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:732]  Unable to create the rendering window
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:732]  Unable to create the rendering window
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:732]  Unable to create the rendering window
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:739] Unable to create the rendering window

/usr/local/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo3.rb:320: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000002a8
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
.................................................................................................................................................................

I have tried version 3 & 2 (ign-gazebo2,ign-gazebo3) via source install and binary install ..
all give the same error, no installation errors or build errors..
just that error when i run it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24644/ignition-gazebo-running-problem/) by [Amr Elsersy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24856/amr-elsersy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sean Yen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8363/sean-yen/) on 2020-03-25**:
I am seeing the same problem. I got my installation from this instructions: https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/install_ubuntu

What should I look into? My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are troubleshooting instructions for that issue on the Ubuntu source install page: https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/install_ubuntu_src#troubleshooting

They should apply equally for the debian install.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amr Elsersy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24856/amr-elsersy/) on 2020-03-26**:
thank you Louise :D

**Comment by [behc0004](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30899/behc0004/) on 2021-08-14**:
Hello, I am facing the same issue.

[ign-1] /usr/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo5.rb:438: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000008
[ign-1] ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

However I cannot find the solution in the troubleshooting instructions. Can you give me more hints? Thanks.